# How do I properly transform a normal Python application into PySpark version

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am a beginner for PySpark, recently I tried to submit a simple python application(batch resize pictures) to my spark cluster. I can run the application through pycharm successfully and when I submittend my application to spark, the images are resized as well.

this is my original Python code:

```
import os
from PIL import Image
size_64 = (64,64)

for f in os.listdir('.')
    if f.endswith('.jpg'):
        i = Image.open(f)
        fn, fext = os.path.splitext(f)
        i.thumbnail(size_64)
        i.save('resize/{}_64'.format(fn, fext))
```

Then I transformed it into a way that I thought I can submit my python application properly:

```
import os
from PIL import Image
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

APP_NAME = "ImageResizer"

def main(sc):
    size_64 = (64,64)
    for f in os.listdir('.')
        if f.endswith('.jpg'):
            i = Image.open(f)
            fn, fext = os.path.splitext(f)
            i.thumbnail(size_64)
            i.save('resize/{}_64'.format(fn, fext))
print 'done'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName(APP_NAME)
    conf = conf.setMaster("spark://10.233.70.48:7077")
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
    main(sc)
```

However, I was told that I did not actually use spark at all (I think so as well but I just don't know how). I am wondering how can I properly transform my original code into the Pyspark way.

Can anyone familiar with pyspark help me out? And any suggestions on where I can properly and systematically learn how to write PySpark applications?
Thank you

Comment: Is this a typo?: i - Image.open(f)

Comment: @nfreze yes, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now you are not using spark at all. You are simply using the SparkContext as a variable you pass to your main function (and then do nothing with). In order to use PySpark, you need to rethink your application. Commands like `os.listdir('.')` work fine on a single machine, but if you run it on a cluster of computers which directory does the `.` refer to? The machine where the job was submitted? The local directory on every machine? A shared network drive? If you are just running on one machine (for tests that is plenty). You can start to use Spark by simply parallelizing the list (turn it into an RDD). You can then apply operations on the RDD like `map`, `filter`, and `reduce`

```
s_list = sc.parallelize(os.listdir('.'))
s_jpg_list = s_list.filter(lambda f: f.endswith('.jpg'))
def resize_image(f):
   i = Image.open(f)
   size_64 = (64,64)
   fn, fext = os.path.splitext(f)
   i.thumbnail(size_64)
   out_path = 'resize/{}_64'.format(fn, fext)
   i.save(out_path)
   return out_path
s_jpg_files = s_jpg_list.map(resize_image)
print('Converted Images:', s_jpg_files.collect())
```

Comment: very impressive!!!! thank you so much for the help! I'm now trying to apply the changes that you mentioned above and "rethinking " my application. Hope I can get it fixed soon. Do you know how can I systematically learn how to write proper pySpark application (I didn't learn map, filter, and reduce before [like a pure beginner])? BTW during the weekend I actually made some changes on my original code and I can resize my images properly, yet I think I did not use spark at all still

Comment: you are right, when I only run on my pycharm, your revised version will resize the images. but when I submitted to spark, it didn't. Since I am running on the cluster, I want to change the os.listdir('.') to a specific path on my master node but I don't know how. Could you please teach me how to properly specify a path for the situations that you mentioned, like The machine where the job was submitted / The local directory on every machine / A shared network drive?

Answer (score 0):

*but the images are not resized* - this is not the same as application failure. When app is submitted it uses application specific working directory. There won't be any files to process there and it exists without doing any work.